# select parent and some childs with a filter by linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have three classes:
OrderSet - Order (1:n) and OrderDetail (1:n)

OrderSet and Order has each a property 'Status'.

I want a receive a construct with all OrderSet with Status='open' and all regarding Orders with Status='open'.

I tried this:

```
var orderSet = db.OrderSet
      .Where(x => x.Status == 'Open')
      .Where(x => x.Order.Any(y => y.Status == 'Open'))
      .Include(x => x.Order.Select(q => q.OrderDetail))
```

But I got all Orders, also with Status 'Closed'.

What is my fault?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Does this code even compile?

Comment: Provide `OrderSet` and `Order` models

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to ignore `OrderSet`s which contain any `Order` that doesn't have an "Open" status, you may use:

```
var orderSets = db.OrderSet
      .Where(os => os.Status == "Open" && os.Order.All(o => o.Status == "Open")
      .Include(os => os.Order.Select(o => o.OrderDetail));
```

If you want to include those `OrderSet`s but only ignore the child `Order`s that don't meet the said condition, there's probably no way to do that without modifying the collection of OrderSets returned by the query.

If that's what you want to do, one way to achieve that would be like this:

```
var orderSets = db.OrderSet
      .Where(os => os.Status == "Open")
      .Include(os => os.Order.Select(o => o.OrderDetail)).ToList();
foreach (var orderSet in orderSets)
{
    orderSet.Order.RemoveAll(o => o.Status == "Open");
}
```

Comment: With this code I got no data all all. (count = 0 for OrderSet) If I change the "All" to "Any" I got 1 Orderset with two Orders (one with Status=Open, one with Status=closed)

Comment: If you get no data, that's because no records meet the conditions used. Is what's described in the first paragraph actually what you want? If yes, then make sure you actually have order sets with open status **AND** all child orders also have an open status.

Comment: If that wasn't what you were after, did you read the last paragraph? Is it what you want or is it something completely different which you need to clarify?

Comment: "If yes, then make sure you actually have order sets with open status AND all child orders also have an open status"  I need only Orders with Staus=Open. There are two Orders in Orderset (one with Status=Open and one with Status=closed. I want to get the Orderset with the only opened Order. So, the condition "AND all Child orders also have an open status" is not true, because only one of these orders has the Staus=Open

Comment: @Nunzio Then, read the last paragraph of my answer. You need to get all the OrderSets with an Open status (including all the child orders), store the result in a list, and then go through the list to remove any child orders that do not have an open status.

Comment: OK, sorry. I misunderstood your answer. Now it is clear. Thank you!